# webapi post request returns Null exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple post method in Web API controller which accepts `HttpRequestMessage`. Somehow the XML is not getting parsed to `HttpRequestMessage`. I have configured the app to use `XmlSerializer`

Trying to pass simple XML to it but giving me Null reference exception

```
public class SyncSubscriptionController : ApiController
{       
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(HttpRequestMessage req)
    {    
        var data = req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

Sending a post request from Fiddler:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:11033
Content-Length: 1852
Content-Type: text/xml

Body:
<customer>
<customer_id>1234</customer_id>
</customer>
```

Global.asax

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Comment: So you are saying `req`  is Null?

Comment: I don't see any problem in code. It works as expected.